# Creating stars on dodecahedron surface

Tags: three.js

I am pretty new to three js and I am trying to create some stars on Dodecahedron Surface. However, I got an errors on getRandomPointOnDodecahedron. Any help on how to create that function. Working file: https://github.com/Triple1331/Question/blob/main/Question/starsOn.js

Answer (score 0):

var colors = [];
//calculate colors for each vertex
...
geom.setAttribute( 'color', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ) );